# Laravel Axios Doesn't Send Correctly Data to Backend Then Returns 422 Status Code

Tags: php, laravel, axios

My code, which I tested yesterday and worked correctly, is not working now. I've had some results by trying to read the error messages.

First of all, I want to say that this is a login process. Using Axios, I receive the data in the form and send it to the back-end, and if everything is correct, I log in and redirect it to the dashboard. A classic login process.

Today, when I wanted to log in to develop new things, I saw the error code 422 returned, and when I printed the incoming data on the server-side, I saw something like this:

```
// $request->all(); result
Array
(
    [------WebKitFormBoundary0OBe87BBjSLuzX6z
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "email"

example@example.com
------WebKitFormBoundary0OBe87BBjSLuzX6z
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

example.123!
------WebKitFormBoundary0OBe87BBjSLuzX6z--
)

// Laravel Error
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"email":["The email field is required."],"password":["The password field is required."]}}
```

I haven't made any changes or updated anything in this part of the system for about three months. So I don't understand why it's not working. However, the form element comes incorrectly on the javascript side, and the Axios request is sent successfully. Here is where I prepared the form:

```
let data = new FormData(form);
axios.post(url, data).then(function (response){
...
}
```

Comment: _"However, the form element comes incorrectly on the javascript side"_ - and that is supposed to mean what, exactly?

Comment: You got boundaries in what you are receiving on the server side, so did your form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set? And if so - why, for a simply login form?

Comment: You can see request->all() data at the top. Is there any mistake? So I think the elements shouldn't come this way.

Comment: @CBroe not setted multipart to form. I'm using like that: <form class="form w-100" novalidate="novalidate" id="kt_sign_in_form" action="#">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I examined the Axios versions (I'm using it via CDN), I saw that it was due to an error in the v0.27.1 version. However, when I looked at Unpkg from the official CDN links, I saw that it was upgraded to the latest version, and when I included the Unpkg cd for testing, the problem was solved.

This version fixes the problem: https://github.com/axios/axios/releases/tag/v0.27.2.